# Bootstrap v2 accordion with bootstrap v3 - Which class changed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code: http://www.bootply.com/A6h7uQRmSt

This is what it looks like with bootstrap 2: http://jsfiddle.net/qdqrT/121/

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        This is where i do not need child elements
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
        Collapsible Group Item #4
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

May I ask why it looks different with bootstrap 3? Have the names of some classes changed between the two and if so, is anyone able to tell me what the bootstrap3 equivalent is please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap v3 is a significant upgrade and so lots of things have changed between v2 and v3. You need to update your HTML markup to conform with the new changes otherwise things won't work as expected. Basically, v3 is not backwards compatible with v2.

- See http://getbootstrap.com/migration/ to get details on how to migrate from v2 to v3.
- See the Boostrap [v3 accordion documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples) for example code and to understand how it works in v3.